# Group items in a table based on value in column and count

Tags: jquery

I have the following table:

```
echo '<table>
        <thead">
        <tr>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Dest Server</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody>';

foreach($xml->children() as $textxml)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $testxml->attributes()->host . "</td>";
  echo '<td>' . $testxml->attributes()->destserver . "</td>";
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Output:

```
Host          Dest Server
server1       ss01
server2       ss01
server3       ss02
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var index = $("table thead th:contains('Dest Server')").index() + 1;  //index is zero based, nth-child is 1 based.
    var cells = $("table tbody td:nth-child(" + index + ")");

    var ss01Count = cells.filter(":contains('ss01')").length;
    var ss02Count = cells.filter(":contains('ss02')").length;

    console.log(ss01Count, ss02Count);
</script>
```

Question: I want to display number of occurrence of ss01 and ss02 in Dest Server column but the console log only shows 0, 0 rather than 2, 1

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem has to do with the execution of your script. Is it placed after the table or is it executed before the table is rendered in the page. As you can [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/4GYNm/) your script works just fine when placed inside $(function(){ ... });

```
$(function(){

    var index = $("table thead th:contains('Dest Server')").index() + 1; 

    var cells = $("table tbody td:nth-child(" + index + ")");

    var ss01Count = cells.filter(":contains('ss01')").length;

    var ss02Count = cells.filter(":contains('ss02')").length;

    console.log(ss01Count, ss02Count);
})
```

Comment: Ah you are right silly me. I have moved it below the table and its working now. Thanks